# Liferay Webservices not starting

Tags: liferay, jboss7.x, liferay-6

I'm trying to use Liferays webservices (viewable at /api/jsonws), but my Liferay installation is not starting any of this services. I'm running Liferay 6.1.3 on JBoss 7.2. This problem occures on three different servers. Same Liferay & JBoss setup on all 3. Only difference is that one of those servers had Liferay 6.2 running briefly. 6.2 allowed access to all webservices from /api/jsonws. Sadly I cannot switch back to 6.2 for several reasons.

Got a log entry stating that no service is configured.

```
16:36:03,291 DEBUG [ServerService Thread Pool -- 268][JSONWebServiceConfigurator:221] Configure JSON web service actions
16:36:03,299 DEBUG [ServerService Thread Pool -- 268][JSONWebServiceConfigurator:236] Configured 0 actions in 7 ms
```

Same liferay on a local tomcat works pretty fine and starts all webservices. So my question is if there is any kind of global on/off switch or if I have to set any special settings? I'm running out of ideas right now ...

Thanks in advance and regards, Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth checking portal-ext.properties file in your server.

There is a setting to turn JSON web services on/off. I guess it may be set as "false" in your case.

> ```
> #
> # Set this property to true to enable JSON web services. Note that setting
> # this to false will cause portlets that make JSON web service calls from
> # working.
> #
> json.web.service.enabled=true
> ```

Comment: I doubt portal-ext.properties beeing the problem. json.web.service.enabled=true, jsonws.servlet.hosts.allowed=VALID_IPs, json.servlet.hosts.allowed=VALID_IPs ... Shouldn't be any blocker in this file.

Comment: As only certain VALID_IPs are specified, Are you accessing /api/jsonws from one of the IP mentioned ?

Comment: I just pasted VALID_IPs so that my comment is not too long. My IP is part of that list. So this shouldn't be an issue.